# How to set firefox as a default kde-help-browser?

Tags: firefox, kde

I'd like to do it, because of the firefox extended-selection feature (acutally it is a XULrunner feature - which is a firefox engine).

Another solution would be to find out where all the KDE help handbooks are located. Do you happen to know that?

**Edit**: knowing where they are won't help - since them are in a docbook format - not in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Firefox as your help browser in KDE.

From the Kubuntu-docs package:

> Though KHelpCenter is recommended, all documentation in this package
>   is HTML, which means you can view it with any web browser by browsing
>   to /usr/share/doc/kde/HTML/en/kubuntu/"section".

Also the KOffice-doc-html package:

> The documentation will be installed into the usual directories
>   /usr/share/doc/kde4/HTML/"language"/"app"/, for instance
>   /usr/share/doc/kde4/HTML/en/kword/.

In other words, you will just have to use KHelpCenter, or manually convert the files from docbook format to HTML (which I will not cover here as that is out of the scope of the question).